# I have a list of tuples and i need to find the minimum of these using the value and if the values are same i need to sort them by key

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, tuples

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT

    lst = list()
    name_grade = {}

    for i in range(int(raw_input())):

    name = raw_input()
    grade = float(raw_input())
    name_grade[name]= grade

tem = list()

for k,v in name_grade.items():
    tem.append((v,k))

sorted_list = sorted(tem)
second_low = min(sorted_list[1:])
T = tuple(second_low)
print T[1]
```

### It worked for input :

4
Prashant
32
Pallavi
36
Dheeraj
39
Shivam
40

expected o/p : 
Pallavi

### but when it had equal values it failed:

5
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39

### O/P :

Berry

### expected :

Berry
Harry

Comment: Your output is correct though, it has Berry and Tina ordered since they have the same number 37.21

Comment: @busfault i know, but they want me to sort alphabetically if 2 students have same grades, the objective was to find the 2nd lowest grade and here 2 have the same 2nd lowest grade. i dont know how to again sort alphabetically

Comment: It would make more sense to store a set of just grades and then sort that. Also store a dict of grade to list of students. After you find the grade you want, index into the dict with that grade to get your list of students.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python expert, but I'm trying to think of trying to simplify things. For instance, I don't think that using a dictionary is necessary, not if it's just a simple function you want to be doing often.

I would just create the functions I need as lambda functions. Ex.

```
f = lambda: raw_input("INPUT NAME: ")

g = lambda: input("INPUT GRADE: ")
```

Then I'd do something like this, define a function in which you can put the number of students in as a value ("number"), and that will produce something usable as output. In this case, I produce a nested list.

```
seq = []

def names_grade(number):
    seq = []
    for i in range(number):
        seq.append([g(),f()])
    return seq
```

To me for now it doesn't matter what format the output is. A nested list, i.e. a list-within-a-list can be useful. Lists are better for certain things. Dictionaries are great for other things, but for simple functions like this, I would try to go with what is simplest and what is easiest to work with for sorting and so forth. There are also other data types in Python, like Sets or whatnot. It's important to choose the type that best suits the problem at hand.

So what I got was this, after running it:

```
>>> x = names_grade(2)
INPUT GRADE: 30
INPUT NAME: Alex
INPUT GRADE: 40
INPUT NAME: Marc
>>> x
[[30, 'Alex'], [40, 'Marc']]
```

Again, I'm not an expert, but I do something like this, define a function to give me the smallest, in this case with only 2 inputs, which can always be changed later on..

```
def smallest(x,y):
    if x<y:
        return x
    else:
        return y
```

Then I ask and get the following:

```
>>> smallest(x[0],x[1])
[30, 'Alex']
```

This isn't a full "solution", it's more of a way of looking at and analyzing the problem to try to find the best solution.. We do a concept inventory if you will, look at what functions we will need and what values, what types of data/values, etc. Then we build from there. It doesn't matter if it doesn't solve the problem right at the start. We start building it, part by part, and we test everything every step of the way to make sure it passes.

In any case, I think that for this kind of problem, a more "functional paradigm" or "style" can be useful. Just define the functions you need, as lambda functions or whatnot, the "smallest" function, the functions you need, then you can use things like "map"....

Remember, map takes the form:

```
r = map(func, seq)
```

It applies the function ("func") to every item of a sequence ("seq"). So once you have a "names_grade" list of some sort, you can use map and whatever functions you created for the problem at hand. Then you can ideally do it all in very few lines of code. You can use "functional composition" too, and generally you're working with functions that are one-liners, I find much more readable. Add a docstring or other form of documentation to describe in the appropriate amount of detail what the function does, what inputs (and type of inputs) it takes, what it does, and what outputs (and types of outputs) it produces.

Lastly, this is pretty much the first question I ever answer on Stackoverflow, so I hope that I have not broken any rules. Please don't be too harsh on me, I'm only here to help, not be personally attacked for not knowing how to write proper answers. Good day to all.

*Edit: I kept thinking about this over the course of the last few hours, and I think I maybe found a solution. Just sort the tuples by grade, the names are going to be in alphabetical order anyway if two grades are the same. Ex.

```
>>> names_grades_tuple = [
    ('alex', 15),
    ('jane', 20),
    ('david', 19),
    ('john', 15),
]

>>> sorted(names_grades_tuple, key=lambda grade: grade[1])
[('alex', 15), ('john', 15), ('david', 19), ('jane', 20)]
```

What I don't understand is why the original program is structured the way it is. It seems rather abstruse to me, almost esoteric. In the example I give above, if you wanted the second one, then just index at the second value after it is sorted. Ex.

```
>>> sorted_tuples = sorted(names_grades_tuple, key=lambda grade: grade[1])
>>> print sorted_tuples[1]
('john', 15)
```

Does any of this make sense? I guess that maybe I don't quite understand the question. Sorry if I have wasted anyone's time here.

**Edit 2: Using this reference (Ref. https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting), I found another way. Create a class, instantiate it with the names, grades.. then use the operator module. Ex.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr((self.name, self.grade))

student_objects = [
    Student('john', 15),
    Student('jane', 12),
    Student('dave', 10),
]

from operator import attrgetter

>>> sorted(student_objects, key=attrgetter('grade', 'name'))
[('alex', 15), ('john', 15), ('allen', 17), ('jane', 20)]
```

The trick is that with attrgetter, you can sort on multiple levels. Here I am sorting by grade AND by name. Isn't that what was being asked?